# How to eliminate unwanted horizontal scroll-bar on re-sizing window by media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

i have problem with this code and the problem is that before 1200px everything is OK but after re-sizing to 1200px and more ( before width of scroll bar, for example chrome scroll-bar width is 17px ) before 1218px, we will see unwanted horizontal scroll-bar annoying us.

i want to solve this problem but i don't know how.
anybody knows how? so please guide me.

link of my codes and online test:
https://codepen.io/mostafaeslami7/pen/xZePXq?editors=1100

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="inner-header">header</div>
</div>

<div class="body">body</div>

<div class="footer">
    <div class="inner-footer">footer</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my css:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

body{
    background-color: orange;
}

.header{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-header{
    background-color: black;
}

.body{
    height: 3000px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.footer{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-footer{
    background-color: green;
}

.header,
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.inner-header,
.inner-footer{
    height: 100%;
}

.inner-header,
.body,
.inner-footer{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){
    .inner-header,
    .body,
    .inner-footer{
        width: 1200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your example. The scroll bar appears as I reduce width below 1000px (on Chrome), the width you specified for inner-footer. That seems normal to me. If you prefer to cut off the content rather than showing a scroll bar you can use overflow: hidden, as the answer suggests. It's not clear what you want. The content is wider than 1000px. You have to either make the content able to flow and size smaller than 1000px or decide what to do with the overflow.

Comment: If there is no specific reason for the width to be 1000px you can set it to max-width: 1000px

Answer (score 3):

I know it a old question. but i had like to share this, Hopping someone will find it useful and will save someone's day.

So, There is no quick way, You will have to do some digging and find yourself the element which is causing overflow. Thus, creating unwanted horizontal scroll and pain in your ass. Normally one way would be to just write

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and hope that overflow-x on body will remove that horizontal scroll bar but some times you have to apply `overflow:hidden` to you main container of the site. Which likely works all the time or most of the times. like,

```
.main_container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

There are some tricks that can help you find those overflow elements such as using below JavaScript script, just open console and execute it there

```
var docWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;

[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  function(el) {
    if (el.offsetWidth > docWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);
```

OR you could execute jQuery one,

```
$.each( $('*'), function() { 
    if( $(this).width() > $('body').width()) {
        console.log("Wide Element: ", $(this), "Width: ", $(this).width()); 
    } 
});
```

or you can use this little jquery snippet. It will logging out the elements directly in console along the elements width, which can help you to easily highlight them on hover in your console (at least in Chrome).

```
 $.each($('*'), function() { if ($(this).width() > $('body').width()) { console.log($(this).get(0)); } }).length;
```

or if you still can't find that particular element use this below trick,

```
//Open inspector -> “New Style Rule”:
    * {
        outline: 1px solid red;
    }
```

You can always add: `opacity: 1 !important; visibility: visible !important;` if you think you might have a hidden element but usually the above works without extra effort.

Hope it helps someone. Happy digging.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really recommend it but you can use `overflow-X:hidden` on the `body` element (not the element with a class of `.body`*). It's not as though you need to see anything outside of the sides of your container anyway...right?

<sup>* you should really not use that name for a class, it's unnecessarily confusing.</sup>

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {
    overflow-X: hidden;
  }
  .inner-header,
  .body,
  .inner-footer {
    width: 1200px;
  }
}
```

Ideally, you should adjust the design to allow for this though. Different browsers treat the scrollbars differently when it comes to calculating the viewport width.

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XXQVgV)

Comment: no . its not the way . this work just for this simple expample . i have many elements in my divs . they are not simple and it would not show all elements ...

Comment: Then you need to make a more complete demo which shows why this will not work for you,

Comment: i solve it very easy. if you define min-width media queries = width + scroll-bar width ( for example in chrome is 17px or in opera is 15px but for sure we say 20px ) the problem will be solve.

new link of code: 

codepen.io/mostafaeslami7/pen/JGVLdK?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

You can change your .inner-footer from width: 1000px to max-width: 1000px; and that will fix the issue.

Comment: thats nice but i want to avoid max/min-width. do we have any way to solve with javascript ?

Comment: May I ask why you want to avoid max-width? It is certainly far preferable to use max/min width than to have to implement javascript so set sizing

Answer (score 0):

Here you change code like that. `overflow-x: hidden;` is hidden the horizontal scroll bar.
 
 
`body{`
 
    `background-color: orange;`
 
    `overflow-x: hidden;`
 
    `overflow-y: scroll;`
 
`}`

Comment: no . its not the way . this work just for this simple expample . i have many elements in my divs . they are not simple and it would not show all elements ...

Comment: you can use the `overflow-x: hidden;` never shows the horizontal bar.otherwise you clearly say your specification.

Comment: if we use that, we just hide it . but still vertical scroll-bar annoying us to see many section of divs on exact 1200px width because of vertical scroll-bar width. i want to remove affect of vertical scroll-bar to see all sections of divs ...

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this in quite a few ways - one of which is changing your `width: 1000px` to `max-width: 1000px`

Another might be simply styling / hiding the scroll bar with some -webkit prefixes. Wouldn't recommend this route for multiple UX reasons but if you want to read up on styling scrollbars - check out [this resource](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/).

Lastly you could specifically target the x-axis scroll bar with `overflow-x` and remove / hide it by setting this to `hidden`. Again - this method is not the best. How would a user know content is off the page without the scroll bar?

Answer (score -1):

i solve it very easy. if you define min-width media queries = width + scroll-bar width ( for example in chrome is 17px or in opera is 15px but for sure we say 20px ) the problem will be solve.

new link of code:

codepen.io/mostafaeslami7/pen/JGVLdK?editors=1100